# How to add auto layout on UICollectionView programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, uicollectionview

I create a `uicollectionview` programmatically, and I want to add auto layout constraint on the collection view so that I can change the frame later. But the following code is not work.

I am trying to initialize the collectionview like this:

```
        self.rootCollectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height - 100) collectionViewLayout:[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc]init]];
        self.rootCollectionView.dataSource = self;
        self.rootCollectionView.delegate = self;
        self.rootCollectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [self addSubview:self.rootCollectionView];
        [self.rootCollectionView registerClass:[CASlideSwitchViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CASlideSwitchViewCell"];
        self.topConstraint = 100;
        float topCon = self.topConstraint;//self.topConstraint is a CGFloat property,
        UICollectionView * cv = self.rootCollectionView;
        cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        NSArray * constraintArray = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[cv]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(cv)];
        NSArray *constraintArray2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-topCon-[cv]-0-|" options:0 metrics:@{@"topCon":@(topCon)} views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(cv)];
        [self addConstraints:constraintArray];
        [self addConstraints:constraintArray2];
```

then after I receive the data, I am trying to change topConstraint based on the data. Like this:

```
if (number <= 1) {
    self.topScrollView.hidden = YES;
    self.topConstraint = 0;
}else{
    self.topScrollView.hidden = NO;
    self.topConstraint = 100;
}
[self updateConstraints];
[self.rootCollectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
[self.rootCollectionView reloadData];
```

However, the top margin of the `UICollectionView` is always 100.

Do I miss something? Or it is not right to add auto layout like that?

Comment: try to add auto layout from nib it will be easy in that way

Comment: @nischalhada I know that nib is a easy way to use, but in this project, I am not allowed to use nib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `self.topConstraint` is a float not a NSLayoutConstraint so you can not update the constraint. You can instead of using

```
NSArray *constraintArray2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-topCon-[cv]-0-|" options:0 metrics:@{@"topCon":@(topCon)} views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(cv)];
```

You should use

```
NSLayoutConstraint *topLayoutContraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:cv
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                toItem:self
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                            multiplier:1.0
                              constant:100];

NSArray *constraintArray2 = @[
                              topLayoutContraint,
                              [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:cv
                                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                           relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                              toItem:self
                                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                          multiplier:1.0
                                                            constant:0]
                              ];
```

then you can

```
if (number <= 1) {
    self.topScrollView.hidden = YES;
    topLayoutContraint.constant = 0;
} else {
    self.topScrollView.hidden = NO;
    topLayoutContraint.constant = 100;
}

[self setNeedsLayout];
[self.rootCollectionView reloadData];
```

Comment: the constraint is correct but it seems not work on UICollectionView which created programatically.

Comment: `self.rootCollectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height-100) collectionViewLayout:[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc]init]];

NSLayoutConstraint *topLayoutContraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:cv
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                toItem:self
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                            multiplier:1.0
                              constant:0]; `

Comment: I have tried the upper code, which create by 100 margin, and add a constraint with 0 margin immediately, but it still not work.

Comment: I'm sorry for my little mistake. you should use `topLayoutContraint.constant = 0;`

Comment: By the way, `cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;` cannot be removed

Comment: I have notice the `constant = 0` and have modified it in my project. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Great!! after I add `cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;` it workes! It is awesome! Thank you so much!

Comment: I’m glad that helped you:)  You can tickmark on right button so, it will be helpful to others :)